# neo4j Spatial 'Spring data' - Index with the same name but different config exists

Tags: neo4j, spatial, spring-data-neo4j

**Update**: Got this working but leaving this post intact. I was facing this issue only with 'POINT' index type. Learnt through a post in the forum that the Spatial plugin needs to be added. I got it working after that.

**Request/suggestion**: Since the Index type is known at the time of throwing the exception, can a hint be provided as well? 
I have the following nodes - 'Policy' consisting of 'Location's and each 'location' contains 'Address'. 'Address' also has Lat/Long to support Spatial.

```
double latitude, longitude;
@Indexed(indexType = POINT, indexName = "LAT_LONG")
String wkt;
public void setLatLong(String lat, String lon){
this.latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
this.longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon);
this.wkt = String.format("POINT( %f %f )", longitude, latitude); }
```

I am using Spring Data and when I save the Policy - entire Object graph is being persisted. Only one 'policy' gets added I am getting the error
I checked the lat/longs and they are different for both the addresses 
1st Address - 26.716125,-80.049147
2nd Address - 25.696616,-80.256872

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index with the same name but different config exists!
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RetrievedIndexInfo.checkConfig(RetrievedIndexInfo.java:54)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RestIndexManager.checkIndex(RestIndexManager.java:56)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RestIndexManager.forNodes(RestIndexManager.java:74)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.createIndex(ExecutingRestAPI.java:167)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.createIndex(RestAPIFacade.java:249)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.createIndex(SpringRestGraphDatabase.java:108)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.createIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:93)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getIndex(Neo4jTemplate.java:650)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory$IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListener.valueChanged(IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory.java:77)
```

`
Step through the debugger and found this line to be causing the creation of Index second time.
org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl

```
final boolean useExistingIndex = indexType == null;
```

Comment: Before giving up, thought to Google one last time. Luckily got help through this link - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/1CfVrwyVhew.

Comment: Use a separate, concrete index name for your spatial index.

Comment: Thanks Michael, as I updated my question - got it working by adding the Spatial plugin.